# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_kerberos'

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, kerberos

Granted, I'm fairly new to Python so bear with me. I just installed this successfully using pip and can verify that it's in the correct location (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages). However, when I try to run this very simple script, I get the error in the post title. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

**Version information:**

- Python - 2.7.13
- requests - 2.18.4
- requests_kerberos - 0.12.0

My script:

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth

myusername = input('Enter your username: ')
mypassword = input('Enter your password: ')

proxy = { 'http' : 'x.x.x.x:8080', 'https' : ':x.x.x.x:8080' }
auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(myusername, mypassword)

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
print('HTTP Status:', r.status_code, '\n')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Give us the full error.

Comment: Can you show `sys.path`?

Comment: @Stuart Barrett Were you the person who did https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/issues/110? issues on Github.

Comment: @StuartBarrett Have you added Python to your system path.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the installation should be inside `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` and not `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR my computer has `lib` not `Lib`

Comment: @ds_secret yeah that's the standard directory. May just be a typo, but wanted to check

Comment: by default, NTFS paths are not case sensitive and CPython "understands" this (as it makes os path calls through win32 api). In your script, before you try to import from `requests_kerberos`, do a quick `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`, please.

Comment: @cowbert 

C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python36.zip
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Babel-2.5.0-py3.6.egg
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg

Comment: @cowbert Here's the rest:
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\barren\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\barren\.ipython

Comment: So, apparently, my instance of Spyder 3.6 is using those directories instead of what I thought it was using (C:\Python27\). I copied it over to the site-packages in anaconda3 and the error has changed to a different missing module. So, that was it. Thanks @cowbert

Comment: @ds_secret Yes, it was me, but I closed that because I felt like I put it in the wrong place. So, I opened this on stackoverflow.

Comment: @StuartBarrett next time, use anaconda to switch to the correct python environment before running pip to install packages. (or use the PyPI installer interface from within Spyder; it should have one...)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an IDE like PyCharm:

- Open the terminal and type: `pip show requests-kerberos`.

  This will output: `Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
- Copy the path: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
- Go to PyCharm setting (on Mac 'preferences')
- Under the section 'project' select 'project interpreter'
- Click on the gear on the right of the field 'project interpreter'
- Click 'show all' and then on the small icon that says 'show path for the selected interpreter'
- Click on the plus sign and paste the link you copied before.
- Click ok